# source issue with my image element and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Alright hey guys.  Trying to get this clock functioning with the pictures.  I have more than just the one but if I can get the one figured out I can handle the others.  After much searching I found out you can't use string interpolation within an attribute but I kept it there to show I tried.  The second one I think "should work" and it shows the variable i'm trying or pic0, pic1 and so on but it's a string not the actual module i'm importing at the top (in the actual app I have them all imported but cut them down for brevity on the question.  Any assistance??  I'm bashing my head what is causing this issue

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import pic0 from './0.png';

export default class Clock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.incrementTime = this.incrementTime.bind(this);
    this.dayInWords = this.dayInWords.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      clock: new Date(),
      day: (new Date()).getDay(),
      hours0: 0,
      minutes0: 0,
      seconds0: 0,
      hours1: 0,
      minutes1: 0,
      seconds1: 0
    }
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    let intervalTimer = setInterval(this.incrementTime, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalTimer);
  }

  incrementTime() {
    this.setState(currentState => {
      return {
        clock: new Date(),
        seconds1: ((new Date()).getSeconds())%10
      };
    });
  }
  render() {
    return(
        <div className='panel-body imgContainer'>
          <img src={pic0} alt='the digit 0' />
          <p>Know this one doesnt work but kept here to show I tried it</p>
          <img src={`pic${this.state.seconds1}`} alt='seconds1' />

          <p>I think this should work and the src is what I want as the variable that im importing at the top but its just a string not the variable.</p>
          <img src={'pic' + this.state.seconds1} alt='seconds1' />

          <p>This is the end goal im trying to accomplish but im trying to see if it can be done using this.state.seconds so its kind of "dynamic" and the source changes every second thus changing the image</p>
          <img src={pic0} alt='seconds1' />
        </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

this is what i'm seeing it's the image not showing the src is the "variable" im importing at the top but it's not actually calling that variable/module sorry if my terminology is wrong i'm clearly pretty new at this.

[image]

Thanks for all the assistance!!!!

Comment: src={`pic${this.state.seconds1}`} this is not working ?

Comment: Nope unexpected token error cuz you aren't using backticks for string interpolation but when using back ticks it still doesn't "interpolate" correctly

Comment: are you bundling this with webpack?

Comment: yes.  although it's the create-react-app package not me building it from scratch. I know I can use this with 
    <img src={require(blah blah)} />
i'm just curious if I can do it more dynamic with how I have displayed in the code
if not that is fine it just seems like that works everywhere else in React :)

Comment: src={pic0} should be working. I'm confused, what's that `0` image you pasted? Is that not the image you're looking for?

Comment: src={pic0} is working when I put that in directly.  When I try and interpolate or concatenate the inspector shows pic0 as the src but it's a string not the variable/module i imported at the top.  The 0 in the screen shot is the src={pic0} and the broken image is the other ways that i'm trying to understand how to make them work if it's even possible

Comment: You have to reference that imported file directly. You can place that on state, or in a variable somehow, but it must be referenced. Strings with the same name won't cut it.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you for that clarification!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this was clarified in the comments, for future visitors of this post - you need to reference the imported image directly:

```
import pic from './myImage';

// works
<img src={ pic } />
```

It can be placed in the state, or some other variable, but can't be accessed via a string with the same name:

```
// Doesn't work
<img pic={ 'pic' } />
```